# Exchange 2007 OWA - Can log in, but no graphics / broken images

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007, outlook-web-app

We have an OWA server that we need to setup on Exchange 2007 SP1 on Server 2008. OWA is enabled under client access. I am able to get to the OWA web site, login, and authenticate. However, all of the graphics are broken ([X] = broken image):

**Connected to Microsoft Exchange [X] M Find Someone [X] [X] Options ...**

*NOTE: can't use image tags as a new user*

I'm pretty sure this is the result of a bad root pointer somewhere, but I can't seem to find the location. Since this affects all relative paths, the site doesn't "work" either, likely due to scripts with bad pointers.

I can't get the graphics themselves to display either. Trying:
https://mail.mydomain.com/owa/8.1.375.2/themes/base/logob.gif

does not display an image, despite looking "correct" based on the directory structure in:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\ClientAccess\owa\

Any ideas?
Exchange is otherwise *knock* working fine.
Thanks!

Comment: If you get a network capture, do you see 404s being sent or what? What kind of firewall/load balancing devices are in front of tis CAS server? Tried re-applying the service pack? Thanks, Brian Desmond Active Directory MVP

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hi it is easier to execute the following procedure.

FIX:
Step 1) Load the Exchange Management Shell

Step 2) Navigate to your Exchange Bin directory via the management shell - usually C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\Bin

Step 3) Run the UpdateOWA.ps1 script (done by entering .\UpdateOWA.ps1)

Comment: This also fixed my permission settings. All images were also redirected to the forms login

Comment: This fixed my missing images issue.

Answer (score 3):

The latest rollout appears to be missing both gifs and scripts, but OWA always referred to the folder corresponding to the latest rollup, rather than the folder 'current'.  My solution was to copy the contents of E:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\ClientAccess\Owa\8.1.240.5 to E:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\ClientAccess\Owa\8.1.393.1.  This is assuming that your previous working version was 8.1.240.5 and the current one is 8.1.393 (SP1 rollup 9).  A handful of the files already existed in destination folders, which I opted not to overwrite.  NB! make sure you make a backup copies of the folders.

Answer (score 3):

The issue has been resolved, OWA is up & running. It involved having to un-and-re-install IIS 7 (*which is just awful, BTW*), un-and-re-installing Client Access components, and deleting & re-creating all virtual directories.

Thanks to all for your info & suggestions.

Comment: Dang, I'd just found a link mentioning OWA images not showing up being a result of IIS metabase corruption.  There was a tool in the IIS6 resource kit for clearing that out, but nothing that I can find for 7 so far.  Anyway, for your amusement http://searchexchange.techtarget.com/generic/0,295582,sid43_gci1353415,00.html#

Answer (score 1):

This work to me.

Open IIS, go to default web site, search and select owa content.
Locate the current version and go to properties and select directory security.
Probabily in the Authentication and access control the security is wrong, set this to Enable anonymous access and dismark any other security box.

This error ocurred when I applied update Rollup 12 sp3.